# Clunking/grating sound coming from front right when turning left at speed

Tags: noise, suspension, old-cars

My car is a 1983 Mitsubishi Tredia, front-wheel drive, right-hand drive, manual transmission. When I turn left at moderate speed, the car makes a grating sound, lasting about half a second. It seems to come front the front end, on the right-hand side. After straightening, it clunks again but less loudly (as if correcting whatever went wrong when turning).

It's not a rotational sound, which is why I don't think it's a CV joint -- sounds more like a suspension-related issue. To clarify, this sound doesn't occur when I turn at low speed, or with stationary wheels. It also doesn't happen when going over bumps, as long as the wheels are straight, but if I go over a bump when the wheel is turned left, then it's extra loud (this happens when turning into my driveway).

I've just replace the suspension bushings, and this didn't fix the issue. The CV joints are relatively new (about 3 years old). The car is well-maintained. Could it be something to do with the strut mounts? Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the car have standard height wheels and suspension? Does it have any additional body kit?

Comment: It's all standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a couple of things, but I suspect that you have a something rubbing on the body. When you turn while moving, the car will lean as the suspension compresses. That might make just enough difference for it to make contact.

Turn the wheel to about where you hear the clunk. Get someone to sit on the corner of the car while you look underneath. Look for scratches or rub marks on anything that has minimal clearance.

If you suspect an area put some paper masking tape on it and go for a drive. Make it clunk a few times then check again.

Edit: if you jack the body up and take weight off that corner can you move anything? Does the coil spring move?

Comment: Thanks! Seems like good advice. Will let you know if I work it out.

Comment: It can be frustrating finding clunks, but Its gotta be there somewhere. It would be worth taking it to a garage that can put it on a hoist and give everything a prod with a pry bar.

Comment: Update: I tightened the bolts on all the bushings by a couple of turns, and that seems to have fixed the noise (or at least made it inaudible among the other usual sounds). The radiator was also a bit loose, and I tightened that, but I don't think that was the main problem.

Comment: Cool. :) I hope thats sorted it.